# android: res/values vs res/xml as resource path

Tags: android, xml, resources

Wasnt able to find information on that on the net.

Basically i would like to know what to put in which directory. Its clear to me that files containing the strings for my views have to be in res/values as thats the only way i get their ids generated, but what are you putting in res/xml then? For me, the folder atm only contains the xml for preference activity.

Answer (score 1):

About **res/xml**:

> For miscellaneous XML files that configure application components. For example, an XML file that defines a `PreferenceScreen`, `AppWidgetProviderInfo`, or `Searchability Metadata`. See [Application Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) for more information about configuring these application components.

About **res/values**:

> For XML files that are compiled into many kinds of resource. Unlike other resources in the **res/** directory, resources written to XML files in this folder are not referenced by the file name. Instead, the XML element type controls how the resources is defined within them are placed into the `R` class.

and

> Define values such as booleans, integers, dimensions, colors, and other arrays.
>   Saved in **res/values/** but each accessed from unique `R` sub-classes (such as `R.bool`, `R.integer`, `R.dimen`, etc.).

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html).